# Write output file from gulp task using through

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to gulp and JS in general. But I have this gulp file that uses [protagonist](https://github.com/apiaryio/protagonist) to validate a file. The task was written by someone else and it works correctly. Now I need the output of Protagonist to build a file from the parsed structure but I can't understand where in the script should I get it. Also the package `through` makes things harder for me to understand.

What would I need to do in order to write the result of the function `protagonist.parse()` to a file from within gulp.

**Gulp file**

```
var through = require('through2');
var protagonist = require('protagonist');

gulp.task('protagonist', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.build_blueprint)
        .pipe(gulpProtagonist({type: 'ast'}))
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});

function gulpProtagonist(options) {
    return through.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {

        protagonist.parse(file.contents.toString(), {type: options.type}, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return cb(new PluginError('gulp-protagonist', error));
            }

            try {
                if (result['warnings'].length > 0) {
                    var msgs = result['warnings'].map(buildWarningMsg);
                    var args = ['error'].concat(msgs.map(genError));
                    self.emit.apply(self, args);
                }

                cb(null, file);
            } catch (e) {
                cb(new PluginError('gulp-protagonist', e));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just using [`gulp-protagonist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-protagonist)?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung That is a wonderful suggestion.